# PHP shortcode use

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have placed ad codes outside my main container on my website, positioning them in my header.php file. They look fine on desktop view, but the problem arises on a mobile or tablet device where they overlap with the main content area.

I found a plugin that provides the shortcode [notdevice][/notdevice] for handling media queries (the shortcode basically implies that whatever content goes inside it should only be displayed on a desktop because the user is not viewing on a tablet device or phone device). How would I go about using that shortcode in the header.php file? I know that it doesn't work like shortcode does on a post or page, but the idea would be the same:

[notdevice] 
Ad code 1 
Ad code 2
[/notdevice]

My site is beeandcompany.com. Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: by simply `do_shortcode()`'ing it. I mean [**A Simple Google Search**](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wordpress%20shortcodes%20in%20template) would've shown you the answers you seek.....

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Darren in the comments you need to use do_shortcode(). For your situation your code will look similar to this:

```
<?php 

echo do_shortcode('[notdevice]');

echo $adcode1;

echo $adcode2;

echo do_shortcode('[/notdevice]');

?>
```

Here is a link to the documentation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this code in your header.php file :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[notdevice]');?> 

Ad code 1 Ad code 2 

<?php echo do_shortcode('[/notdevice]');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone who contributed answers. I tried the do_shortcode, however, it was not working. Instead, the echo line and shortcode would just show up as a line of text at the top of both my desktop and mobile screen. I ended up using a function code for it and it worked. Here is a solution for anyone who might come across this thread and need a similar solution:

```
<?php if (function_exists('wpmd_is_notdevice') && wpmd_is_notdevice()) :?>
This will show up if user is only on a desktop
<?php else : ?>
This will show up if user is on anything other than a desktop
<?php endif; ?>
```